# Crystal Report: remove duplicates

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal Report to pull Charges and the Transactions associated with those Charges. One Charge might have many Transactions attached to it, and one Transaction might cover many Charges. As I put this report together, the Transactions would repeat themselves if there were many Charges in that revenue code group. And if there are many Transactions for one Charge, the Charge would duplicate itself. I also have to do subtotal and grandtotal for these Charges and Transactions, so if there are duplicates in data, the totals would also incr
How do I remove those duplicates?

Below is the SQL query for this report:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A123Test_ChargeOnly."enc_nbr", 
    A123Test_ChargeOnly."revenue_code_id",A123Test_ChargeOnly."Charge",
    A123Test_TransOnly."Tran_Description", A123Test_TransOnly."tran_amt"
FROM
    { oj "NGProd"."dbo"."123Test_ChargeOnly" A123Test_ChargeOnly 
    INNER JOIN "NGProd"."dbo"."123Test_TransOnly" A123Test_TransOnly ON
    A123Test_ChargeOnly."enc_nbr" = A123Test_TransOnly."enc_nbr"}
ORDER BY
    A123Test_ChargeOnly."enc_nbr" ASC,
    A123Test_ChargeOnly."revenue_code_id" ASC
```

Comment: Does Crystal have distinctcount() or distinctsum() functions?  I don't use Crystal anymore, but I think it does.  Would they work?

Comment: Which SQL (Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer etc.) are you using?

Comment: Crystal Report does have distinctcount() but not distinctsum(). I also tried using the "Select Distinct Records" option and it does eliminate SOME but not all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than joining the two tables, I suggest UNIONing them - something like:

```
SELECT 'Charge' record_type, enc_nbr, revenue_code_id, Charge, '' Tran_Description, 0 tran_amt
FROM "NGProd"."dbo"."123Test_ChargeOnly"
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Transaction' record_type, enc_nbr, '' revenue_code_id, 0 Charge, Tran_Description, tran_amt
FROM "NGProd"."dbo"."123Test_TransOnly"
ORDER BY 2, 1, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there is a specific 'suppress if duplicate' option in the 'sections' expert of Crystal Reports ....